# How to make div expand towards top when height modifies?

Tags: html, css

So I have a div which appears above a button when the button is pressed, position fixed. It has a height and a width, but I'd like to let the heigh modify in case that it needs so, using min-height will do that but if the height modifies it will expand the div towards bottom, how do I make it expand towards top instead? Like the bottom part of the div is FIXED and won't move an inch, but the top part can go up to make room for more content inside the div.

Comment: Please add your code here. CSS HTML that replicates your scenario. On a first thought you could do that by moving the div up with the exact px as it's growth in height. That might be difficult ( = not possible ) with only CSS ( as you say it will change height dynamically )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
position: fixed;
```

should be applied with *bottom css* and not top css

so try replacing the top value CSS with the bottom value CSS.

```
Eg: 
."div class" {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 10px;
}
```